# What is the production process like for a doujinshi to be sold at Comiket?

Tags: doujinshi, comiket

Are there steps for a doujinka to take when making fan-made manga that would be sold at Comiket? For example, the Comiket would be held in April. When will they start making the doujin?

Is the production process of fan-made manga similar to that of regular manga? I mean the doujinka had to like print the doujin themselves, while the mangaka don't. And they need to advertise their work. Do they have deadlines, too? What preparations do they need to make first?

Below is the timesheet of *Nurarihyon no mago*'s author:

[image: Hiroshi Shiibashi's timesheet]

Do they manage the production and distribution of their fan-made manga? Or do they just print the manga and sell it?

Comment: from what I've read in doujin's afterwords, doujinka do have deadlines to send their finished product to the printers and to the ComiKet comittee so they get a space for their booth (printing can even be done by themselves so it can be dismissed, unless you're making thousands of copies), but that aside they can work at their own pace as long as they make those deadlines. Then again, ComiKet is just one event, there's also the Comic 1, SC, series specific events like Reitaisai for Touhou, etc. For merchandising, it's mostly just posts on pixiv or twitter with samples of what they'll be selling